# IIS6 SMTP server sending blank 'From' addresses within bounce messages

Tags: smtp, iis-6

I have a basic SMTP setup configured using IIS6 to send out site emails on my server.

I've been scanning through the badmail directory and have noticed the following type of notification occur. It looks as if an error has occurred while trying to send a bounce message back to myself.

```
550-5.7.1 not RFC 5322 compliant:
550-5.7.1 'From' header has non compliant domain name.
550-5.7.1 To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail, this message has been blocked
```

and

```
The message sender was <>.

The message was intended for the following recipients.
    bounce-box@test.com
```

It is trying to send the bounce message back to my gmail account (as shown above), but google rejects the message because there is no 'From' field being set by the bounce message.

How do I get the SMTP server to send out emails from a particular alias - I would assume a default needs to be set along the lines of postmaster@serverdomain.com? Or is there an extra header item in the emails I send which can specify a 'bounce from' address?